# What is the reasoning/intuition behind $P(X=x)=0$ for a continuous distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Why is $P(X=0)=0$ for a continuous distribution?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA4JkHKZM50 Maybe this Video by 3Blue1Brown clears things up.

Comment: This is a defining property of continuous distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in general $$P(X=x)=P(X\le x)-P(X<x)=F_X(x)-\lim\limits_{t\to x^-}F_X(t)$$ and by definition a random variable $X$ has continuous distribution if its cdf $F_X$ is continuous.